# I ran into a weird bug in c++ where a statement calculating an addition of 2 small integers overflow into a long long value

Tags: c++, c++11

I recently ran into this weird C++ bug that I could not understand. Here's my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef vector <int> vi;
typedef pair <int, int> ii;

#define ff first
#define ss second
#define pb push_back

const int N = 2050;

int n, k, sum = 0;
vector <ii> a;
vi pos;

int main (void) {
    cin >> n >> k;
    for (int i = 1; i < n+1; ++i) {
        int val;
        cin >> val;
        a.pb(ii(val, i));
    }

    cout << a.size()-1 << " " << k << " " << a.size()-k-1 << "\n";
}
```

When I tried out with test:

```
5 5
1 1 1 1 1
```

it returned:

```
4 5 4294967295
```

but when I changed the declaration from:

```
int n, k, sum = 0;
```

to:

```
long long n, k, sum = 0;
```

then the program returned the correct value which was:

```
4 5 -1
```

I could not figure out why the program behaved like that since -1 should not exceed an integer value. Can anyone explain this to me? I'm really appreciated your kind helps.

Thanks

Comment: Don't include *anything* from `bits` directly. These are designed only to be included from standard headers, which are what *you* then should include.

Comment: `#define pb push_back` don't do this either. While it saves you some time for typing, it makes the code (much) harder to read as `push_back` is well known to any experienced coder whereas `pb` needs to be remembered separately (or coder has to lookup again)...

Comment: `i <= n` is more elegant than `i < n + 1` (only applies for integrals, not floating point types!)

Comment: Thanks for your advice I'm really appreciated those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, on your machine, your `size_t` is a 32-bit integer, whereas `long long` is 64 bit. `size_t` always is an unsigned type, so you get:

```
cout << a.size()      -   1
//        ^ unsigned      ^ promoted to unsigned
//      output as uint32_t
//                ^ (!)
a.size() - k - 1
// ^ promoted to long long, as of smaller size!
// -> overall expression is  int64_t
//                          ^ (!)
```

You would not have seen any difference in the two values printed (would have been 18446744073709551615) if `size_t` was 64 bit as well, as then the signed `long long k` (`int64_t`) would have promoted to unsigned (`uint64_t`) instead.

Be aware that `static_cast<UnsignedType>(-1)` always evaluates (according to C++ conversion rules) to `std::numeric_limits<UnsignedType>::max()`!

Side note about `size_t`: This is defined as an unsigned integral type large enough to hold the maximum size you can allocate on your system for an object, so the size in bits is hardware dependent and in the end, correlates with the size in bits of the memory address bus (first power of two not smaller than).

Answer (score 1):

vector::size returns size_t (unsigned), the expression `a.size()-k-1` evaluates to an unsigned type, so you end up with an underflow.